# array.length--; show TypeError, what can I use instead of that to have no empty gap in array after deleting?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

TypeError: Member "length" is read-only and cannot be used to resize arrays.

It's solidity 0.8;

```
  uint[] public array;

  function removeElement(uint i) public {
    array[i] = array[array.length-1];
    delete array[array.length-1];
    array.length--;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solve array.pop(), it deletes last element and resizes array (decrements by 1)

should be used `array.pop();`
instead of:
`array.length--;`

and `delete array[array.length-1]` is redundant

Comment: Doesn't array.pop just take the last element off the array - I thought you wanted to remove the ith element?

Comment: yes exactly, I've already updated comment as you posted. I have only problem with array.length--. removing ith element it's in the code of question just by swaping ith with last (it's useful only when order isn't necessary)